# Unexpected error on ACDOAuthSigner connection: Error Domain=XPCObjectsErrorDomain Code=2

Tags: ios, testing

Does anyone seen this issue in iOS? This is related to twitter account deletion from settings app when your app is in background. My app needs login via twitter and I present user list of accounts in a table by reading all twitter accounts registered in account store. Once I do successfully login to the app using one of the accounts, I go to settings app, delete the twitter account from which I did login in my app. I go back to my app and and it crashes. Is this a bug in the apple code?

Thanks